# IVY to find set of dependent projects

Tags: set, ivy

We have around **100 components** (more coming in near future) configured to use IVY+ANT build system.

Problem is that its **slow :(**. To speed up the system, we would like to use ANT multi-threaded functionality but because these components can have dependencies on each other we can not simply do that. The possible solution to this problem is to first we find out set of components in LIST which are dependent on each other and are independent (**Like MAEVEN**).  Once we have this list we can then distribute build task to ANT.

So is there any way we can get this sort of LIST from IVY (out of the box)? We have looked at the ivy:buildlist task but it does not seems to give this type of result. I am wondering how difficult is to implement that, this should be fairly easy to return as IVY already have the information and the dependency graph so why its not listed?

**Additional Information**

We have many projects i.e. separate projects and they all have their own ivy.xml defining dependencies to 3rd party jars as well as on each other. For example we have Project A, B and C with ivy.xml as follows;

**Project A - ivy.xml Only 3rd Party Dep**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="XYZ" branch="14" module="A" />
    <configurations ...
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="A" type="" ext="jar" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" conf="test"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**Project B - ivy.xml Defining Dependency on Project A**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="XYZ" branch="14" module="B" />
    <configurations ...
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="B" type="" ext="jar" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
                    <dependency org="XYZ" name="A" rev="14" conf="compile,test"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" conf="test"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**Project C - ivy.xml Only 3rd Party Dep**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://repository.temenosgroup.com/xsl/version-doc.xsl"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="XYZ" branch="14" module="C" />
    <configurations ...
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="C" type="" ext="jar" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.2" conf="test"/>
            </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Now if you see we can not use multi-threaded build for **Project B** because we have to build **Project A** first and then kick off B. In above scenario if **somehow** we find out this we can execute **two(2) threads** at the same time (which is OK and desirable), in one thread building set/group 1 which is A and then B and in the other thread set/group 2 which only has C.

So my question is how can I get this individual group/set information from IVY?

Comment: I looked at that exact problem, and realistically, you're going to have to re-implement a large chunk of Maven (or other modern tools) functionality (the reactor in the case of Maven). Which suggests considering a migration to Maven if that problem is essential to your build.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a bit more about your setup? What do you mean 100 components? 100 jars that are stored in your local repository, that your product is made from 100 separate items, or that you specify in a single `ivy.xml` 100 separate items? Do you have a local corporate wide repository? What type of repository is that?

When you initially fetch items from Ivy, they're stored locally on the computer. If you use `<ivy:cachepath/>` or `<ivy:cachefileset>`, the jars aren't even copied to the local working directory, but are saved in the cache. Subsequent builds should be much faster without having to download anything from the remote repository.

We use Artifactory as our corporate repository. On Jenkins, we clean the cache before each build, and that adds about 2 minutes to the build time. We feel this is reasonable for Jenkins. On local builds, the cache is not cleared. Most developers find the build times quite tolerable. This is especially true since I've rewrote most of the build scripts that knocked build times from 10 to 20 minutes to under 2 minutes for most builds. If jars have to be fetched from the repository, it may add another 2 to five minutes to the build time, but since the cache isn't cleaned out on local machines on a regular basis, this rarely is an issue.

There's an `<ivy:report>` which list jar dependencies for a project. Would that help you? Or, do you need some sort of master list?

Again, without more information, it's hard to know what your issue may be.

---

## Addendum

Okay, I see what you're trying to do. I think you may misunderstood how Ivy works...

The idea is not to build project "A" when project "B" builds. The idea is that project "A" publishes to your site wide artifact repository `a.jar`. When project "B" builds, it doesn't need to rebuild "A", it merely pulls out of the repository `a.jar` and builds.

I don't know if you have a local artifact repository. We use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) as our Maven/Ivy repository. Actually, we make Artifactory a Maven repo. We don't *publish* Ivy artifacts via `<ivy:publish>`. We use `<ivy:makepom/>` to create a `pom.xml` then use `mvn deploy` to get the artifact into our repo. This way, we can use the artifact for either Ivy or Maven since it has a `pom.xml` associated with it.

We use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) as our continuous integration server. In projects that create jars files for other projects to use, we use `mvn deploy` to deploy each and every build to our *Snapshot* repository. In Ivy, I believe this is the same as an *integration* status jar. When the developer thinks their changes on Project *A* are ready for prime time, they *promote* the Jenkins build to publish `a.jar` to our Maven *Release* repository.

Developers usually use the Release repo, but by modifying their `ivy.xml` file, they can pull off the latest build of `a.jar` our of the *Snapshot* repo to use for testing purposes.

Most of this complication comes from the fact that we have both Maven and Ivy projects that use the same jars. I'm not all that familiar with Ivy, and it could be that Ivy would do all of this for me and there's no need to worry about Ivy/Maven compatibility. We simply wanted to keep everything *Maven compatible*.

If you have nothing but Ivy projects, you could use the *status* parameter of the `<info>` entity to specify if a jar is in the *integration*, *milestone*, or *release* state. I know that `<ivy:publish>` can use `status` to override the status in the `ivy.xml` file. This means that most of the time, Ivy projects publish each build with the *integration* status, and when developers are ready, they can use Jenkins promotions to publish that jar under that *release* or *milestone* status. Artifactory works well for Ivy *publish* as well as Maven *deploy*.

We do have something that sort of does what you asked -- a reverse lookup of projects that depend upon jars -- but it's not to *speed up builds*.

Our foundation developers using the *Loosy-Goosy* method of development. They will change classes and methods with abandon. Method names will be changed, the number of parameters, or even removed. Projects that depend upon them suddenly don't build which can be a bit of a consternation two weeks before a release.

Therefore, I have a Perl script using `XML::Simple` that goes through our repo looking for all Ivy dependent projects (easy to find since the `ivy.xml` is in the root of the project, then go through the `ivy.xml` to look up dependencies, and build a reverse map. I don't need anything more than first level dependencies which makes it simple.

I use this *reverse map* to tell Jenkins to force build dependent projects whenever a dependent jar is *deployed* to our Maven release repo. For example, if a developer deploys a new version of `a.jar`, Project *B* will rebuild, but a project that depends upon `b.jar`, but not `a.jar` will not rebuild.

This is just a sanity test for us. I could give you the code, but it's customized for our site, and didn't take me long to produce. As I said, I'm only interested in first level dependencies, so building this map was pretty simple. It merely allows me to rant and rave to the Project *A* team when their changes breaks projects that depend upon `a.jar`.

Comment: I think I see what you want.

Comment: Thanks David for the info and its is helpful to understand how IVY is built. Yes we have local as well as remote repo. It would be a great help if you can share the Perl script. Thanks